# A version of implicit function theorem when sections are not everywhere smooth?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, implicit-function-theorem, differential-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Let $V_1, V_2 \rightarrow M $ be smooth vector bundles over a manifold $M$ and $s_1: M \rightarrow V_1$ 
a smooth section transverse to the zero set and $s_2: M \rightarrow V_2$ a continuous section 
such that $ s_2 : s_1^{-1}(0) \rightarrow V_2$ is a smooth section, transverse to the zero 
set. Let $p\in M$  be a point such that 
$$ s_1(p)=0, \qquad s_2(p) =0. $$
Does there always exist a solution $p(t_1, t_2)$ near $p$ such that 
$$ s_1(p(t_1,t_2)) =t_1 \qquad s_2(p(t_1,t_2)) = t_2 $$ 
if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are sufficiently small? To make sense of sufficiently small we can 
just chose some metric on $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Note that if I said that the section $p \rightarrow s_1(p) \oplus s_2(p)$ is smooth 
and transverse to the zero set, then the answer is obviously yes (by implicit function 
theorem). It seems that one should be able to imitate the  proof of implicit function 
theorem (ie contraction mapping principal) to justify what I am asking. But I am not sure 
of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by your assumption $s_2$ is only smooth along the submanifold $s^{-1}(0)$ of $M$ and might even jump in directions transverse to it. So it is easy to come up with a counterexample: $M=\mathbb R^2$, $s_1(x,y)=x$, $s_2(x,y) = y$ for $x\le 0$ and $=y+1$ for $x>0$.

But if you assume that $s_2$ is strictly differentiable on $M$ along $s_1^{-1}(0)$, then is true in a somewhat weaker sense. See

- MR0817719  Reviewed Ver Eecke, Paul Applications du calcul différentiel. (French) [Applications of differential calculus] Mathématiques. [Mathematics] Presses Universitaires de France, Paris, 1985. 397 pp.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a very clear counter example. Regarding your second comment, suppose I assume that $s_2:M \rightarrow V_2$ is smooth. Does that mean the answer to my question is yes? Or do I have to modify the question slightly? You said it's true in some weak sense. Usually that means that I have to have a different notion of what it means to have a solution.   

Comment: @Ritwik: Weak means, that the implicitly given function is just strictly differentiable at each point of $s_1^{−1}(0)$. This means $lim_{x≠y→x_0}\frac{f(x)−f(y)}{x−y}$ exists (1-dim version).